# Meaning of ses_anonymous in frontend login in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

In my TYPO3 installation which has frontend login possibility - I can see that some of the frontend sessions (fe_sessions) has ses_anonymous set to 1. I am not sure what is exact meaning of that and under what circumstances TYPO3 can create ses_anonymous for frontend user? Can anyone explain that?

Comment: In the "migrateFeSessionDataUpdate.php" it says:
"With the new Session Framwework the session data is stored in fe_sessions. To avoid that data is truncated, ensure the columns of fe_sessions have been updated. This wizard migrates the existing data from fe_session_data into fe_sessions.
Existing entries in fe_sessions having an entry in fe_session_data are updated.
Entries in fe_session_data not found in fe_sessions are inserted with ses_anonymous = true. (Found in sysext/install/Classes/Updates/)

Comment: And a comment in "DataSessionBackend.php" mentions: "This session backend requires the 'table' configuration option. If the backend is used to holds non-authenticated sessions (default if 'TYPO3_MODE' is 'FE'), the 'ses_anonymous' configuration option must be set to true." (sysext/core/Classes/Session/Backend) –Does this help in any way?

Comment: @RobertWildling you should turn your comments into a proper answer. ;-)

Comment: @MarkusBrodala: These are just copy&pasted the from the TYPO3 core. There is not much understanding on my side behind that. So I'd prefer to leave them as comments, since the real value of information has been provided by a core developer. Your answer on the other hand provides real value and even a possible usage scenario - that's a good answer! – However, thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This flag indicates that the session data in question was set for an anonymous user.

This may occur if some (extension) code sets session data without any frontend user being logged in. But this may also occur if session data has been stored while being logged in and simply logging out. The session data may be continued to be used in this case.

A common example for this feature would be a language/country selection which should be stored permanently, no matter if a user was logged in.

Comment: Hi Mathias, we have noticed a similar behaviour like the question owner. We are using a felogin form in combination with secure_downloads extension and sometimes the feuser uids of some secure download log entries are just zero. For this reason I have checked the fe_sessions table and then I have seen that some sessions are set to ses_anonymous = 1. This is kinda bad, because we can't completely track which feuser has downloaded a file. Do you think this issue is based on the same topic?

Comment: You might want to ask in the TYPO3 Slack about this which is better suited for support questions.

Comment: Ok, I will ask there.